# How to make webBrowser background colour transparent

Tags: c#, webbrowser-control

Web Browser has default background colour white. I need to change it to transparent.

I can transparent Form 1 with this code :

```
this.BackColor = Color.LimeGreen;
this.TransparencyKey = Color.LimeGreen;
```

I tried this code to make web browser background transparent but it did not work, so I found this code:

```
private void webBrowser1_DocumentCompleted(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    //this.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Transparent;
    this.SetStyle(ControlStyles.SupportsTransparentBackColor, true);
    this.BackColor = Color.Transparent;
}
```

This did not work either.

Comment: @RufusL in right of this page [link](https://www.aparat.com/aleffamily/live2) i have a comment and i need to Extraction with css code. i Write css code and inject it to thid psge with inline css but i have color in back

Comment: @RufusL [img](http://s8.picofile.com/file/8360373800/check.PNG)

Comment: @RufusL this is a A personal project why?

Comment: @RufusL i just open c# 2010 create windows aplication project and put a webBrowser in from1

Comment: @edrissatiyari, Web browser has no background colors. If you want to change the background color you have done it in HTML or CSS. In the above command link, the web page contains a black background color. May I know why you wanna change the background color?

Comment: @Golda  [img](http://s9.picofile.com/file/8360414342/stack.png) see this img ita winform project i need full transparent because i neeed just cooments for game

Comment: @RufusL its winform bro i see it